# How to create clickable listview in Android using Sqlite3?

Tags: android

I have created listview in Android to show my records. And records are shown as well. Now I want to click on particular record from that listview to show/view particular record. And that record must show another layout for that profile. How to achieve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a onItemClick() event for the listview. Then, when you click on an item, a new intent will be created that will start a child activity that will display the particular record.

```
listView1.setOnItemClickListener(new ListView.OnItemClickListener()
{
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> listView, View itemView, int itemPosition, long itemId)
    {
        Intent launchActivity = new Intent(MyActivity.this, OtherActivity.class);
        startActivity(launchActivity);
    }
});
```